# Is there any notation that can get the left boundary value of an real interval?

Tags: notation, real-numbers, interval-arithmetic

I have an sequence of half-open interval named with $$\langle\tau_i\rangle_{i=1}^3 = \langle [0, 1),[1,2),[2,3)\rangle.$$ I want to get the left and right boundary value of $\tau_2$, which is 2 and 3, respectively. I currently get them by introducing a notation of boundary value of $\tau_i:\tau_i^l$ and $\tau_i^r$. However, I want to consume alphabets as less as possible for index because I am trying to define a data structure which is tuple of 6 or 7 components and many alphabets are consumed for them.

So I want to know the following: is there any notation commonly used for getting left/right boundary value of a closed/open interval $\tau\subseteq\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Maybe you want its infimum, i.e., use $\inf \tau_i?$

Comment: and then $\sup \tau_i$ for the right value perhaps

Comment: thank you very much, that is what I need!

Comment: You  can also use glb (greatest lower bound) and lub (least upper bound)  for inf and sup, which are from Latin infimum and supremum.